# How to dynamically pass Date values to Google analytics API using R?

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I am trying to automate the whole fetching from GA. So I need to pass dynamic date values in"start.date" & "end.date" credentials. How to pass a formula, so the the required date is automatically calculated. The is what i have done...

Comment: show what you have done?

Comment: `RGA` package parse a values such as `today`, `7daysAgo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

1. Just store the formula to another variable
2. convert it into character.date
3. use the variable in the credential